# Was Shomron, the capital of North Israel, supposed to revert to its ancestral owners in Yovel?

Tags: geography, melachim-kings-book-of, real-estate, yovel

[I Kings 16:24](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.16.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) has a king of North Israel buying some empty-ish land and building a new city on it to serve as the capital.

If I understand the laws of Yovel ("jubilee year") correctly, then the city of Shomron/Samaria was not walled in the times of Joshua, and thus reverts to its ancestral owner every 50 years or so.

How did that work, having a full capital city of the kingdom revert back every few decades? Was there a halachic reason why the Yovel wasn't observed? Or perhaps it was supposed to be observed, but simply wasn't as they people were worshiping idols anyhow?

Comment: Maybe a girl inherited it and one of the kings married her.

Comment: https://daat.ac.il/he-il/hagim/hodashim/purim_adar/elizur-zmaney.htm I think this is a summary of a longer piece he wrote elsewhere, but I can't find it now before shabbat

Comment: For some reason I've always understood that Shemer was not Jewish.

Comment: I've found some opinions that the kings of Israel regarded Shomron with the same level of halachic holiness as Yerushalayim. Does Yerushalayim have special status during Yovel?

Comment: @Harel13 Jerusalem was walled at the time the Jews entered Israel, so you could buy land permanently there. Shomron, it appears, was not.

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you! Okay pshat in the verse was as I'd read it, but he points to possible, possible indications that it was a pre-existing old city.

Comment: Other than that. I meant of course something special about Yerushalayim specifically and not all ערים מוקפות חומה מימות יהושע בן-נון.